# Extract lines between 2 patterns

Tags: bash, loops, design-patterns, extract

Using bash...

I wish to iterate over a variable list for each occurance of '_Brkt';

```
echo "$BrackListAllFinal"

DSCF3649-DSCF3651_Brkt
DSCF3649.JPG    2014-07-21 13:34:44    On    1
DSCF3649.RAF    2014-07-21 13:34:44    On    1
DSCF3650.JPG    2014-07-21 13:34:45    On    2
DSCF3650.RAF    2014-07-21 13:34:45    On    2
DSCF3651.JPG    2014-07-21 13:34:45    On    3
DSCF3651.RAF    2014-07-21 13:34:45    On    3
DSCF3652-DSCF3654_Brkt
DSCF3652.JPG    2014-07-21 13:38:24    On    1
DSCF3652.RAF    2014-07-21 13:38:24    On    1
DSCF3653.JPG    2014-07-21 13:38:24    On    2
DSCF3653.RAF    2014-07-21 13:38:24    On    2
DSCF3654.JPG    2014-07-21 13:38:25    On    3
DSCF3654.RAF    2014-07-21 13:38:25    On    3
```

I'm trying to display filenames following each occurance of lines ending in '_Brkt' and stop
on the next occurance, if exists. I'll make a new directory from each line ending in '_Brkt', and move the sequential files after it into the new directory.

I've tried;

```
echo "$BrackListAllFinal" | awk '{print $1}' | awk '/.*\..*/, /_Brkt$/'
```

...and...

```
echo "$BrackListAllFinal" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n '/_Brkt$/,/_Brkt$/p
```

For example...

1. Create a new directory for each line ending in '_Brkt'

   DSCF3649-DSCF3651_Brkt
2. Move the sequential filenames into the new directory.

   - DSCF3649.JPG
   - DSCF3649.RAF
   - DSCF3650.JPG
   - DSCF3650.RAF
   - DSCF3651.JPG
   - DSCF3651.RAF

I can't get lines to display following a line ending in '_Brkt'.
I'm kind of lost on this one, can someone please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's build this up from the start:

First, you want to iterate over the lines of a variable, this needs as while loop with redirection

```
while read LINE; do
  # ...
done < <(echo -e "$BrackListAllFinal")
```

Now you want to extract come lines as a directory: A simple group change

```
THEDIR='.'
while read LINE; do
  SEDED=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/_Brkt$//')
  if test "$SEDED" == "$LINE"; then
    # File line
  else
    # Directory line
  fi
done < <(echo -e "$BrackListAllFinal")
```

And finally you want to fill in your payload

```
THEDIR=''
while read LINE; do
  SEDED=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/_Brkt$//')
  if test "$SEDED" == "$LINE"; then
    # File line: Move the file
    echo -n "Moving file '$LINE' .."
    if test -z "$THEDIR"; then
      echo ".. Error: Directory not yet set"
      exit 1
    fi
    mv "$LINE" "$THEDIR" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if test "$?" == "0"; then
      echo ".. OK"
    else
      echo ".. Error: Move failed"
      exit 2
    fi
  else
    # Directory line: Remember and create directory
    echo -n "Creating directory '$LINE' .."
    THEDIR="$LINE";
    mkdir -p "$THEDIR" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if test "$?" == "0"; then
      echo ".. OK"
    else
      echo ".. Error"
      exit 3
    fi
  fi
done < <(echo -e "$BrackListAllFinal")
```

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. It's difficult for me to incorporate this into what I've done so far. Could you please inform me how to use either sed or awk to perform the selection only. Thank you.

Comment: @voiczed This is not possible: You have state that propagates from one line to the next

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
echo "$BrackListAllFinal" \
    | perl -MFile::Copy=mv -lne 'if (/_Brkt/) { mkdir $d = $_ } else { s/ .*//; mv $_, $d }'
```